# GOSwagger implementation for imported packages

Tags: go, swagger, swagger-2.0

I'm created a project structure like,

`main.go` and `foo/bar.go`

In main.go, imported foo package and used as foo.functionName(). Now i need to write swagger document in bar.go. When i did, ended with the following error message,

```
unable to determine package for /PATH_TO_PROJECT/foo/bar.go
```

Comment: Is your `/PATH_TO_PROJECT/foo/bar.go` in the `$GOPATH`?

Comment: yeah @kars7e!! Added all paths in gopath!! For an example, `/PATH_TO_PROJECT/` is in `$GOPATH` and `/PATH_TO_PROJECT/foo/` is in `$GOPATH`. But not that particular file -> `/PATH_TO_PROJECT/foo/bar.go`.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure in `foo/bar.go` the package declared is `package foo`. Then the function you want to access in the `main.go` file should start with a capital letter. i.e.

`foo/bar.go`

```
package foo

// PrintBar with extra txt
func PrintBar(txt string) string {
    return "bar with txt " + txt
}
```

Then in `main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/username/project/foo"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("in main.go")
    fmt.Println(foo.PrintBar("from main.go"))
}
```

Comment: Function is executing as u described. But i want to use goswagger within that!! That's my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling Debug mode for swagger by adding `DEBUG=1` in front of your swagger command. This should print you what are the paths considered.

If you look at the [source code where this error is thrown](https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/blob/df3d7a3b7f108ca7e36b90e75466acb3165eec51/scan/schema.go#L882:20), you will see this error only happens when file is not in the `$GOPATH`. Double check that you have the program under `$GOPATH/src`.